# SAPUI5: How to bind Arrays or Objects to UI Elements with OData Model?

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I want to bind a ProcessFlowLaneHeader in SAPUI5 to a OData Model in SAPUI5. The texts, and position are no problem to bind.

My problem is  that I dont know how I can bind the property state correctly to a single OData attribute. The state property is excepting an Array or Object, but I would like to give for state and value different attributes in my OData Model.

This is the way when you are manually setting up a Array in the Controller with fixed values

```
                new sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowLaneHeader({
                    text: "{ProcessFlowModel>label}",
                    position: "{ProcessFlowModel>position}",
                    state: [ {
                            "state": "Positive",
                            "value": 100                
                        }
                    ]
                })
```

but I want to bind state and value of the property state to a ODataModel, and it doesn't work. Is my syntax wrong or is this even possible?

```
                new sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowLaneHeader({
                    text: "{ProcessFlowModel>label}",
                    position: "{ProcessFlowModel>position}",
                    state: [ {
                            "state": "'{ProcessFlowModel>state}'",
                            "value": '{ProcessFlowModel>value}'             
                        }
                    ]
                })
```

I know I could do it with multilevel expanded entityset after modifying my OData service, because SAPUI5 is expecting a nested or expanded entity set, but I would like to solve it with single attributes:

My OData output looks like

```
"state": "Positive",
"value": "50"
```

and not like this, and this would be ok as far as i know

```
        "state": [
            {
                "state": "Positive",
                "value": 25
            }
```

So my question also is, how I can bind objects or arrays in SAPUI5 without using multilevel expanded entityset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used the control but my answer would be too long for a comment. From everything I know about UI5 I would expect that you can do the following:

Create a formatter which returns the object in the format that is expected by the control.

```js
formatProcessFlowLaneHeaderState: function(state, value) {
    return {
        state,
        value
    };
}
```

Then use it in your binding

```js
state: "{ parts: ['ProcessFlowModel>state', 'ProcessFlowModel>value'], formatter: '.formatProcessFlowLaneHeaderState' }"
```

If you are wondering about the syntax of the formatter it is using [shorthand property names](https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/).

Also if I understand [the docs](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowLaneHeader%23methods/getState) correctly you don't even need to create an object but can return an array with two values. Then you don't even need the formatter but can use expression binding:

```js
state: "{= [${ProcessFlowModel>state}, ${ProcessFlowModel>value}] }"
```

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, I tried both and wrote my problems in another answer, so that I can add some screenshots

Answer (score 0):

My application didn't found my formatter method so I put it inside the binding:

```
                new sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowLaneHeader({
                    text: "{ProcessFlowModel>label}",
                    position: "{ProcessFlowModel>position}",
                    state: {
                        parts: ['ProcessFlowModel>state', 'ProcessFlowModel>value'],
                        formatter: function (state, value) {
                            return [{ 
                                state: state,
                                value: value
                            }];
                        }
                    }
                })
```